# Debugging a third party app on an android smartphone

Tags: android, debugging, smartphone

Since a few days an installed app on my smartphone is crashing. Now I am wondering if there is a way to debug an app on my smartphone not created by me. I just have the apk file, not the actual code so I guess I'm not able to run it from android studio on my device. (The debuggable flag is not set so it is false if that is important). I know I can install the apk on emulator devices but the app is running on them without problems so I need to now the problem with my smartphone in particular.

Or maybe it's possible to get at least a log file with more information to the crash from my smartphone? I already found some apps that claimed they could do but that didn't work. Does anybody have a device to my situation?

Comment: Capture the logs with `adb logcat`

Comment: I didn't know it also works with a connected smartphone like this. Thank you!